# dompdf no muestra imagen

Tags: php, dompdf

saludos estoy tratando de mostrar una imagen con dompdf y no la muestra me dice `Image not found or type unknown`

segun las instrucciones debo agregar unas opciones y la tengo de la siguiente manera

```
require_once("../dompdf/autoload.inc.php");

// reference the Dompdf namespace
use Dompdf\Dompdf;
use Dompdf\Options;

// instantiate and use the dompdf class
$options = new Options();
$options->set('isRemoteEnabled', true);
$dompdf = new Dompdf($options);

ob_start();

include_once("plantilla_factura_compra.php");

$html = ob_get_clean();

$dompdf->loadHtml($html);

// (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');

// Render the HTML as PDF
$dompdf->render();

// Output the generated PDF to Browser
$dompdf->stream('compra.pdf',array('Attachment'=>0));
```

en la direccion del `include_once("plantilla_factura_compra.php");` simplemente tengo la direccion de la imagen `<img src="../../img/logo_demo.png" alt="">` y no se muestra

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, bueno verifica bien la ruta de la imagen y coloca debajo de `$html = ob_get_clean();` `ob_end_clean();`

Comment: Prueba de este modo: `$options = new Options(); $options->setIsRemoteEnabled(true); $dompdf = new Dompdf($options);`